# If a value is x, display y if condition z is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a calculator that displays a result for 3 different company fees based off 2 different option buttons (form control) in the Excel workbook.

The first option button where 1 = company 1, 2 = company 2, 3 = company 3 which are linked to cell AF2.
The second one is provider type where 1 = Corporate and 2 = Individual - linked to AD2.
The only other relevant cell is account size (D5).

I attempted to use `=IF(AND())` statements. I can only get the first option to compute. I cannot work out the logic with further arguments.

The conditions:
[image]

- If company 1 and corporate is selected **AND** the account is under 500k (D5) return the value of $330 but if the account value is over 500k return the value of $495
- If company 2 and individual selected and account is under 500k, return value of $650, but if account is over $500k return value of $650
- If company 2 and corporate is selected **AND** the account is under 500k (D5) return the value of $650 but if the account value is over 500k return the value of $650
- If company 2 and individual selected and account is under 500k, return value of $650, but if account is over $500k return value of $650
- If company 3 and corporate is selected **AND** the account is under 500k (D5) return the value of $550 but if the account value is over 500k return the value of $551
- If company 3 and individual selected and account is under 500k, return value of $346, but if account is over $500k return value of $345

Can I complete this task with basic Excel functions or do I need to incorporate VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$G$4,CHOOSE(MATCH(L2,{0,500000}),2,1),MATCH(J2,$B$1:$G$1,0)+MATCH(K2,$B$2:$C$2,0)-1)
```

[image]