# Further clarification of INDEX/MATCH/CHOOSE function in excel needed

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to wrap my head around the functions of INDEX/MATCH/CHOOSE in excel. I have been looking up guides to see how the functions operate, however, I have hit a snag.

My spreadsheet has 2 sets of radio buttons.

- One that has companies 1,2 & 3 on them
- And the second is whether that company is using the corporate or individual trustee

The relevant data I have for this function is shown in the picture with the formula below:

[image: My Spreadsheet]

```
=INDEX($L$4:$Q$5,CHOOSE(MATCH(N10,{0,500000}),AD2,1),MATCH(AF2,$L$2:$Q$2,0)+MATCH(M10,$L$3:$M$3,0)-1)
```

I have managed to get the parameters working to see when company 1,2 or 3 is clicked and if its a Corp. or Trustee, however, I cannot for the life of me work out how to get the values below IF the portfolio size (D5) is below 500,000 to display the other value...

The radio buttons for the company link to cell AF2
and the corp./indiv link to AD2

I have tried IF statements through the function however excel did not like the logic. I am sure this is a simple fix but it's throwing me off tenfold, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Please let me know if you need me to provide anymore information

Comment: Change `N10` to `D5`?  where `D5` should be the cell in which you have the `$400,000.00`

Comment: And the `M10` to `AD2` but `AD2` must return either `Corp.` or `Indiv` and the company cell `AF2` must return `1`,`2`,or `3`

Comment: Why the change of user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207209/is-there-a-vba-solution-to-work-out-if-a-value-is-x-display-y-but-only-if-z-con/70207551#70207551